# HTTPPOST Request inside Spring controller

Tags: http, spring-mvc, http-post, httpcookie

I am having a scenario, where I have to make a HTTP POST request from spring controller upon certain condition, but I got stuck in how to pass Cookies from Controller Request to this POST Request as is i.e. with all attributes of the cookie without any intervention.

I tried adding Cookie with below snippet but it didn't worked well.

Here request is `HttpServletRequest`, `httpPostCall` is an object of type `HttpPost`(Apache 4.5.2), we are using *HttpClient*(Apache 4.5.2) to execute this Post call.

```
Cookie[] cookieArrayServletReq = request.getCookies();
for (Cookie cookie : cookieArrayServletReq) {
    LOGGER.info("Name ::" + cookie.getName() + " Val ::" + cookie.getValue());
    if (CommonUtils.isEmpty(cookie.getPath())) {
        LOGGER.info("Path ::" + cookie.getPath());
    }
    if (CommonUtils.isEmpty(cookie.getDomain())) {
        LOGGER.info("Domain ::" + cookie.getDomain());
    }
    httpPostCall.addHeader("Set-Cookie", cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue());
}
```

Comment: when you just want to pass Cookie to other request you would want to use Cookie manager. `Set-Cookie` is for some other purpose. In fact makes more sense in response headers. request header is not a place for `Set-Cookie`

Comment: I tried using cookie store, but after setting all the cookie from servlet request to apache request, upon execution, I get Null pointer exception for publicdomainfilter ... , it would be helpful if someone can help me on just forwarding the servlet cookie to apache request.